# Is there a convention for returning an empty template in Django when making HTMX calls?

Tags: django, htmx

There are cases where I would like to not return any HTML in my view. Is there a good way to do it apart from returning a blank html file?

Here is what I have currently:

views.py

```
def get_suites(request):
    address = request.GET.get('address')
    rental_units = Rental_Unit.objects.filter(address__address=address).order_by('suite')
    # return empty html requests
    if len(rental_units) > 1:
        return render(request, 'suite_list.html', {'rental_units': rental_units})
    else:
        return render(request, 'empty.html')
```

suite_list.html

```
<label for="suite">Suite</label>
<select name="suite" id="suite">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    {% for rental_unit in rental_units %}
      <option value="{{rental_unit.suite}}">{{rental_unit.suite}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
</select>
```

main.html

```
  <label for="address">Address</label>
  <select name="address" id="address" hx-get="/get_suites" hx-target="#suite-wrapper">
    <option value="all">All</option>
    {% for address in addresses %}
      <option value="{{address}}">{{address}}</option>
    {% endfor %}
  </select>
  <div id="suite-wrapper" style="display:inline"></div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just return an empty [httpresponse object](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.2/ref/request-response/#httpresponse-objects) and avoid the render function altogether.

```
from django.http import HttpResponse
...
else:
    return HttpResponse()
```

The is what the render method returns after combining context with template to create HTML, so by simply returning the httpresponse with no HTML you avoid having to look for what isn't there (ie, an empty template)